# SOQL to get parent and related child

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

```
select id,name,Number_of_Subscriptions__c,(Select id from Subscriptions) from Contract
```

In the above scenario, Contract is parent object and Subscription is child object having lookup relationship.

The child-relationship name is "Subscriptions". But i am trying to execute above query it showing me error:

```
ERROR at Row:1:Column:54
Didn't understand relationship 'Subscriptions' in FROM part of query call. If 
you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' 
after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe 
call for the appropriate names.
```

I tried using __r also:

```
select id,name,Number_of_Subscriptions__c,(Select id from Subscriptions__r) from Contract
```

doesn't worked out!!

Any kind  of help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that you have a custom object, Subscription__c, and that the Subscription__c has a (possibly master detail child) lookup field that references Contract, the important details are provided in the lookup field. For example, I have a "Shift_Break__c" custom object that has a lookup to "Shift__c". The field details are as follows:

[image]

It is the value of "Child Relationship Name", plus the "__r" suffix (so here Shift_Breaks__r) since this is a custom relationship, that must be applied in the nested SELECT.

Also look out for whether you are trying to reference a relationship from a different package (namespace) compared to where the query is being executed - in this context you'll need to prefix the relationship name with the package's namespace.

Comment: Hi Phil,
I used the relationship name only in  my query then also it is throwing me error.

Answer (score 0):

I have used relationship name only in my nested SOQL query:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the "Contract" you are querying the same one that has this lookup field? If you click on the "Lookup Options" section's "Related To" link ("Contract") does this take you to a Salesforce "Contract" object, or is it a custom one? If it is a custom object, your query needs to do "... FROM Contract__c".

Comment: It is taking me to the same Contract object when i clicked on Contract Link from 'Lookup option' section.

Comment: OK, and is this custom or some Salesforce object? If it is custom, you have to have the "__c" suffix on the object type name in your query.

Comment: This should be an edit to your question, rather than an answer, I think.

Comment: Looks like subscription might be part of a managed package?  In that case, you'll likely need to append the namespace to the beginning of the relationship, like `MyNamespace__Subscriptions__r`